# Need to hide visited link text on local file in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have an HTML file with thousands of links formatted like:

```
<a href="#">link text</a><br>
<a href="#">link text</a><br>
<a href="#">link text</a><br>
```

etc.

I want to have the visited links not display at all. Essentially what a:visited{display:none;} would do if it were possible. In case you aren't aware, you cannot apply this style to the a:visited pseudo class for security purposes. I cannot use javascript for this particular case. I can use any other CSS ideas that you guys might have. For now I am simply using a:visited{color:white;} on a white background to make the visited link text not display, however that leaves gaps in my list and I would prefer to hide the visited link text all together so that my list is more concentrated and without blank spaces. Is this perhaps possible with a Google Chrome extension?

I've tried Tampermonkey with the following script but to no avail:

```
(function() {
var css = "A:Link, A:Visited, A:Hover {text-decoration: none;}\n\nA:Visited {color:#fff;}\n\n<div style=\"position: fixed; background: none; border: 0px solid #ffcc00; width: 100px; z-index: 100;bottom: 700px;\">\n<a href=\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s- xclick&amp;hosted_button_id=AJ3JLKWPH88GE\">\n<img src=\"https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif\" /></a>";
if (typeof GM_addStyle != "undefined") {
GM_addStyle(css);
} else if (typeof PRO_addStyle != "undefined") {
PRO_addStyle(css);
} else if (typeof addStyle != "undefined") {
addStyle(css);
} else {
var node = document.createElement("style");
node.type = "text/css";
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
if (heads.length > 0) {
    heads[0].appendChild(node); 
} else {
    // no head yet, stick it whereever
    document.documentElement.appendChild(node);
}
}
})();
```

Comment: "I cannot use javascript for this particular case" but you are considering a Chrome extension? Can you explain the situation more?

Comment: I cannot edit the HTML file, however I can control the css stylesheet that it uses.

Comment: Then the answer to "is it possible with a Chrome extension" is "yes, as long as it's possible with a JavaScript file added to it". It may even be simpler to employ [TamperMonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) for the same purpose.

Comment: Just tried with tampermonkey, above is the script I tried but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you use something like: text-indent: -9999px;

Comment: So from what I can find, this is completely impossible.